# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argpartsort'

Tags: python-2.7

In python 2.7.9 I was trying to install `bottleneck` without sudo access and use its one of the functions `argpartsort`. But this is what happens:

```
import bottleneck as bn
bn.argpartsort
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argpartsort'
```

I tried various methods:

```
pip install --user bottleneck
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): bottleneck in $HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bottleneck-1.3.0.dev0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in $HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from bottleneck)
Cleaning up...
```

I tried building from source:

```
 python setup.py install --user
 Installed $HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bottleneck-1.3.0.dev0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
 Processing dependencies for Bottleneck==1.3.0.dev0
 Searching for numpy==1.12.0
 Best match: numpy 1.12.0
 Adding numpy 1.12.0 to easy-install.pth file

 Using $HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 Finished processing dependencies for Bottleneck==1.3.0.dev0
```

I then tried:

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$HOME/.local" bottleneck
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): bottleneck in $HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bottleneck-1.3.0.dev0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in $HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from bottleneck)
Cleaning up...
```

I tried to export environment variable:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
```

but without any luck.

How can I use:

```
 >>> import bottleneck as bn
 >>> bn.argpartsort
```

and get around this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'argpartsort'
```

without sudo permissions

I am on:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie
```

I appreciate your help, however minimal.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is likely nothing wrong with your install.

Check the [Bottleneck 1.2.0 Release Notes](https://github.com/pydata/bottleneck/commit/11a12c7e73f4a8357e5bf35cccf3eedbc8177ca6#diff-0270959f3dd5fb3637134fc695ecd521):

> Functions `partsort` and `argpartsort` have been renamed to `partition` and `argpartition` to match NumPy.